# GET 404 - existing image not found in directory

Tags: html, css, jakarta-ee, glassfish, java-ee-8

I have found many contributions to the core problem of my question, but no adequate solution.

I built a Java EE Web Application, which is based on a few HTML pages. These are formatted by the following styles.css:

```
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 9px;
  color: gray;
}
body > header {
  background-image: url("../img/tau.jpg");
  border-radius: 10px;  
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 9px gray;
}
a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover, h1.title {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px white, 0 0 20px white;
}
```

Whenever I now deploye the application on my local Glassfish Appserver, I get the 404 thrown. The HTML pages are in the root directory, the images in the subdirectory /img and the styles.css in the subdirectory /css.

Unfortunately I haven't found a solution for this simple problem yet. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: try to use background-image: url("/img/tau.jpg");

Comment: Changed from:
GET http://localhost:8080/testapp-web/resources/img/tau.jpg 404 (Not Found)
to:
GET http://localhost:8080/img/tau.jpg 404 (Not Found)

Comment: we need to see your directories tree

Comment: @RZett please provide you directory structure (where you put the image).
It's probably a bit overkill if you are using plain HTML, but in GlassFish you can use EL (Expression Language) in CSS:
`background-image: url("#{resource['img:tau.jpg']}");`
This notation is usually used in combination with JSP/JSF technology.
The image should stay inside `webapp/resources/img`